# Why is the table not able to be selected/viewed in sql plus? [FIXED]

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I tried to create a trigger.

This is the code I used

```
create or replace trigger prod_se15
  after insert on product_se15
  for each row
  begin
  insert into product1_se15@link4bomb2 values(:new.pro_id,:new.pro_name,:new.pro_desc);
  insert into product2_se15@link4bomb3 values(:new.pro_id,:new.pro_cost,:new.pro_profit);
  end;
  /
```

The error

```
2/3      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
2/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/3      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
3/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Note:

1. The table is displayed when `desc product_se15` or `select * from product_se15` command is executed.
2. Tried to grant the privileges method via another user but it did not work.

Fixed
Detailed Error

```
: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object
         SCOTT.PRODUCT1_SE15@LINK4BOMB2
         ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
         ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
         ORA-02063: preceding line from LINK4BOMB2
```

#The password string mismatch

Comment: `product_se15` exists, but - is `product_se15` over the **database link** available to you?

Comment: It's probably `product1_se15@link4bomb2` and `product1_se15@link4bomb3` that aren't accessible.

Comment: @Littlefoot The table was not available via the link. The password on the database link was mismatched thus the link wasn't active at all. Found this after doing it completely on a new database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes you were right. Fixed it. Now working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you fixed it.